# Proving set identity $(A \cup C = B \cup C) \to (A=B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it sufficient to do a membership table as follows:

```
+---+---+----------+---+---+----------+
| A | C |  A  u  C | B | C |  B  u  C |
+---+---+----------+---+---+----------+
| 1 | 1 |        1 | 1 | 1 |        1 |
| 1 | 0 |        1 | 1 | 0 |        1 |
| 0 | 1 |        1 | 0 | 1 |        1 |
| 0 | 0 |        0 | 0 | 0 |        0 |
+---+---+----------+---+---+----------+
```

Therefore A = B?

Comment: A={1}, B={2}, C={1,2}

Comment: You are going to have trouble showing this identity as it is false.

Comment: A={1,2}, B={1}, C={1,2} is a counterexample

Comment: You just need to consider a case where $x \in A; x\not \in B$ and $x$ either in or not in both $A\cup C; B\cup C$. If $x \in A$ then $x$ must be in $A\cup C$.  But for $x \in B\cup C$ but not in $B$ we just need $x \in C$. So if $x \in A\cap C$ and $x \not \in B$ we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is enough to do an inclusion table.  But an inclusion table for three sets will have $2^3=8$ rows.  Yours only has $4$.  You *NEVER* showed a case where $A$ and $B$ disagree!

$A:1, B: 1, C: 1== A\cup C:1, B\cup C: 1$ Verify

$A:1, B: 1, C: 0== A\cup C:1, B\cup C: 1$ Verify

**$A:1, B: 0, C: 1== A\cup C:1, B\cup C: 1$ FALSIFIED**

$A:1, B: 0, C: 0== A\cup C:0, B\cup C: 0$ nothing to be determined as $A\cup C\ne B\cup C$

**$A:0, B: 1, C: 1== A\cup C:1,B\cup C: 1$ FALSIFIED**

$A:0, B: 1, C: 0== A\cup C:0,B\cup C: 1$ nothing to be determined as $A\cup C\ne B\cup C$

$A:0, B: 0, C: 1== A\cup C:1,B\cup C: 1$ Verified

$A: 0, B:0, C: 0== A\cup C:0, B\cup C: 0$ Verified

So it's not true.

====

But it be easier to come up with an obvious counter example.

Let $A =$ the set of all elphants.

Let $B = $ the set of all mosquitoes.

Let $C = $ the set of everything that exists in the universe.

So......

Answer (score 0):

I realized I did the membership table incorrectly - thanks for the comments, the table should've been done like this:

`+----+----+---+-------+-------+----------------------------+
| A  | B  | C | A U C | B U C |          Comment           |
+----+----+---+-------+-------+----------------------------+
| 1  | 1  | 1 |     1 |     1 |                            |
| 1  | 1  | 0 |     1 |     1 |                            |
| 1  | 0* | 1 |     1 |     1 | (counter example possible) |
| 1  | 0  | 0 |     1 |     0 | (not the premise)          |
| 0* | 1  | 1 |     1 |     1 | (counter example possible) |
| 0  | 1  | 0 |     0 |     1 | (not the premise)          |
| 0  | 0  | 1 |     1 |     1 |                            |
| 0  | 0  | 0 |     0 |     0 |                            |
+----+----+---+-------+-------+----------------------------+`

Comment: In your original table you *never* did a case where $A$ and $B$ differed at all.  It be sufficient to just consider the case where A and B disagree and C is false.  In both those case you get counter example.